# how to create order for guest in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, programmatically

I am trying to create an order for guest checkout programmatically. I have gone through a lot of articles. Finally, I got one stackExchange link for creating order. But In that code, they are not showing how to get cart product list and assign to guest checkout.

This is code for reference.

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();


$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('guest');


$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$emailaddress = $_POST["email"];
$confirmemailaddress = $_POST["cemail"];

if(isset($_POST['tel'])):
$telephone = $_POST['tel'];
else:
$telephone = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['postcode'])):
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
else:
$postcode = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['addr1'])):
$street1 = $_POST['addr1'];
else:
$street1 = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['addr2'])):
$street2 = $_POST['addr2'];
else:
$street2 = "Not Applicable";
endif;

if(isset($_POST['city'])):
$city = $_POST['city'];
else:
$city = "Not Applicable";
endif;

$billingAddress =  array (
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'email' => $emailaddress,
'street' => Array(
    '0' => $street1,
    '1' => $street2
),
'city' => $city,
'postcode' => $postcode,
'country_id' => 'GB',
'telephone' => $telephone,
);

$shippingAddress =  array (
'firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'email' => $emailaddress,
'street' => Array(
    '0' => $street1,
    '1' => $street2
),
'city' => $city,
'postcode' => $postcode,
'country_id' => 'GB',
'telephone' => $telephone,
);

$checkout->saveBilling($billingAddress,null);

$checkout->saveShipping($shippingAddress,null);

$checkout->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->collectTotals();

$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'free'));

$checkout->saveOrder();

foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Please help to get code Asap.
Thanks.

Comment: check my answer, if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code --

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); /* your product ID */
$buyInfo = array('qty' => 1); // for simple product

// for configurable product
/* $buyInfo = array('qty' => 1,
                    'super_attribute' =>array(131=>53,142=>50)
   );

     // here 131 color attribute id and 53 is color option(RED) id, 
      142 is size attribute id and 50 is size option(XL) id  
*/
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

// adding billing address
$billingAddress = array(
    'firstname' => 'Mohan',
    'lastname' => 'Raj',
    'company' => 'Webstocks',
    'email' =>  'test@test.com',
    'street' => array(
        'Sample Street Line_1',
        'Sample Street Line_2'
    ),
    'city' => 'City',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => 'State/Province',
    'postcode' => '12345',
    'country_id' => 'NL',
    'telephone' =>  '1234567890',
    'fax' => '123456987',
    'customer_password' => '',
    'confirm_password' =>  '',
    'save_in_address_book' => '0',
    'use_for_shipping' => '1',
);
$quote->getBillingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress);

//set shippingaddress, shipping method, payment method
$quote->getShippingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress)
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery')
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectTotals();

$quote->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
            ->setCustomerId(null)
            ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
$quote->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
```

above code is tested in an external file.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more clarification, you are adding products based on product id, This is for the simple product. If we have multiple products with configurable products, That time how to pass the products ids to Quote.

Comment: @SudhakarSJ, please check my updates answer. for configurable product function `addProduct` will have extra parameter `super_attribute`.

Comment: @SudhakarSJ, I hope my updated answer make sense to you. if not then please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Can you please check this link [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248410/magento-1-9-update-product-quantity-in-quote-programmatically-for-registered-cus]. I am getting an error while updating the quantity in the quote.